# How to draw a graphical element so that its size stays always the same on each machine?

Tags: android, size, graphic

I need to draw a square having the same size on each device. I am planning to draw a graphical button and I don't want it to be much smaller (or bigger) than an average finger.

Is there any way to ensure that an element I draw (square in this case) doesn't get resized? I need it to be always the same size in centimeters on inches.

Regards,

M.K.

Answer (score 0):

on each device compute the graphic's dimensions as: height/density, width/density and other dimensions you have

Answer (score 0):

That is what the DP unit is made for.

This is a very interesting lecture which also shows what happens if you use `px` instead of `dp`: you get different UI sizes on different devices:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

(the specific paragraph is **Density independence**)

You may also want to take a look at android attributes `android:minWidth` and `android:minHeight`